# Errors occur for OpenTok video streaming service

Tags: video-streaming, opentok, videochat

I am an OpenTok user in Japan. I used OpenTok services to build an sample video chat web app one year ago, and it worked great at that time.

Now I have to show this sample app for some demo purposes. However, I found that the video streaming does not work and shows following errors:

```
OpenTok:Publisher:error OT.Publisher.onPublishingTimeout
OpenTok:GlobalExceptionHandler:error OT.exception :: title: Unable to Publish (1500) msg: ICEWorkflow
OpenTok:Session:error 1500 +0ms Session.publish :: Could not publish in a reasonable amount of time
...
```

Same errors occur when I try to open OpenTok's official sample Web app: 
https://opentok.github.io/opentok-web-samples/Basic%20Video%20Chat/

My questions are:

1. Does anyone know how to fix these errors?
2. Does OpenTok even provide video chat service in Japan anymore?

Answer (score 0):

I found the reason by by myself.

It has nothing to do with OpenTok.

"vidyocamera" was added to my browser as a plugin and was set to be the default camera. It causes the errors since it could not provide any video streaming.

Everything worked fine after I deleted "vidyocamera".

P.S. OpenTok "Pre-call Test" tool really helped to debug this problem. It is a tool to test connectivity, expected call quality, client hardware, and client software.

https://tokbox.com/developer/tools/precall_doc/